# How to create and send an excel as an attachment in Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know if it has a way to send a newly created excel file as an email attachment? I can save it to disk, normally but how do I create this excel and attach it immediately to email?
I tried to use

```
$this->export_planilha($id)->download('xls');
```

The program finish in this line.
I'm using Laravel 4.2.

But the code stops at this line. Thank you.

Comment: If you can save it to disk, you can attach it to e-mail via standards Laravel 4 methods :)

Comment: Hi Ivo i like use this in an application with several users requesting this file and his filename just he fix :( how to solve this ?

Comment: There any way to attach the file as stream or string ?